# Does installing ubuntu touch other physical connected hard drives

Tags: installation, grub2, windows, 13.10, ssd

In my computer I have 2 SSDs. One has Windows installed. The other is waiting to be used. If I install Ubuntu 13.10 on the empty SSD is there any chance that a single bit will be written to the Windows SSD without me trying?

Answer (score 0):

No. Unless you choose to format the SSD containing Windows.
Also, Windows default boot will be changed to grub (not overwritten anyway).

Comment: You really want to leave the Windows boot loader in the Windows SSD. But grub defaults to install to sda which usually is the Windows drive.You can disconnect the Windows SSD or use manual partitioning or Something else and on partitioning screen choose which drive to install grub2's boot loader into.  For BIOS based system, if a new UEFI system then post back as it is totally different.

Comment: Yes it's UEFI - I'm posting this as I was concerned about my soldering skills with a 4PDT switch for switching between SSDs and thought it was safer to check if it was necessary. So, with everything left as is, will a clean default install of 13.10 touch the windows SSD? It's sounding like it will and I find that very frustrating.

Comment: Another reason I'm posting this is I have had a similar problem before, around 12.04 I think. In that case I had the Windows drive disconnected when I installed 12.04 and it was great for months - no problems, I used the perfectly adequate bios to choose the boot device. A few months later I think some sort of update in ubuntu seemed to rewrite the bootloader on the windows disk despite it being a different physical device.